# Test Driven Development Understanding Problems

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

Maybe somebody can help me understanding the "Test Driven Development" Method. I tried the following example by myself and i dont know where my understanding problem is.

Assume that we need a function that gives back the sum of two numbers a and b

To ensure, that the function works right, i write several tests. Like creating the sum-object, checking if a and b are numbers and so on .. but the first "real test" of right calculating is the following

```
a=3
b=3
expected value: 6
```

The TDD method allows us only to do so many steps to let the test pass.
So the function looks like

```
sum(a, b){
 return 6
}
```

The Test "3+3" will pass.

Next test is "4+10" maybe.

I'll run the tests and the last test will fail. What a surprise ...

I'll change my function to

```
sum(a, b){
 if(a=3 and b=3)
  return 6
 else
  return 14
}
```

The test will pass!

And this goes so on and on ... i will only add another cases for every test. The function will pass every of this tests, but for every other not listed case it will not and the result is an ineffective and stupid written function.

So is there a foolproof "trick" to not fall into this way of thinking?
I thought, test driven development is pretty straight forward and dumb proof.  Where is the "break even" point when its time to say, that this way of doing tests isn't practicable anymore and switch to the right solution

```
return a+b;
```

???

This is a very simple example, but i could imagine, that there are more complex functions which are obviously not so easy to correct like this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TDD workflow has a 3-part cycle ("red,green,refactor") and it's important not to skip the third part. For example, after your second version:

```
sum(a, b){
 if(a=3 and b=3)
  return 6
 else
  return 14
}
```

You should look at this and ask: is there a simpler way to write this? Well, yes, there is:

```
sum(a, b){
 return a+b
}
```

Of course, this is an unrealistic trivial example, but in real-life coding, this third step will guide you to refine your code into a well-written, tested final version.

Comment: That was the part i forgot: The refactoring! ... On the refactoring step it comes clear that a+b is much shorter than programming just another case again and again .. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of writing test is to know whenever your system is behaving as expected or not. In test we make expectations, assumptions. Basically, we make following

- Set your expectations
- Run the code
- Check expectations against the actual output

We set our expectations for given conditions and test it against the actual output. As developer, product owner, we always know how the system should behave for any given condition and we write tests accordingly.

For example, for the below given pseudo code:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Here method `sum` should return the sum of arguments a and b. We know that,

- The argument should always be integer.
- The output should always be integer type.
- The output should be the sum of two numbers a, b.

So, we exactly know when it would fail and we should write test to cover at least 70% of those cases.

I am a PHP guy, so my examples are in PHP. Regarding, ways to supply the arguments a, b. we have something called data provider. I am giving PHP here as a reference, in [PhpUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) the preferred way of passing different argument is to pass it through [Dataprovider](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers). Visit the dataprovider sample and you will see the example for additions.

> And this goes so on and on ... i will only add another cases for every test. The function will pass every of this tests, but for every other not listed case it will not and the result is an ineffective and stupid written function.

Yes, we try to cover as much part of the cases as possible. The more test covered, the more confident we become on our code. Let's say we have written a method that returns the subsets of array each having 4 unique elements in it. Now how do you approach writing the test cases for it? One of the solution would be to compute the permutation and check the length of array that should not exceed maximum count of array (being each unique element).

> Where is the "break even" point when its time to say, that this way of doing tests isn't practicable anymore and switch to the right solution

We don't have break even in test cases. But we make the choices among different types of test cases namely (unit tests, functional bests, behavioural test). It is upto the developer what type of tests should be implemented and depending upon the types of tests it may vary.

The best way is to implement the TDD in projects. Until we do it in real projects, the confusion would remain. I myself had very hard time getting to understand the Mock and Expectations. It's not something that can be learned overnight, so if you don't understand something it's normal. Try it yourself, give yourself sometime, do experiments ask with friends just don't get exhausted. Always be curious.

Let us know if you still have confusions on it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I think your conclusion to use TDD in practise to see how it works is a good advise. Sometimes its better to begin something without destroy it through excessively thinking.